# Как понять где проинициализирован git и как его удалить?

Tags: git, android-studio

Видимо как то где то я сделал инициализацию гит и теперь когда я складываю тестовые проекты в папку каждый раз в студии выползает окошко которое говорит о том, что "найден гит, не хотите ли подключиться" (Unregistered VCS root detected)?

Мне в тестовых проектах вообще он не нужен, как удалить инициализацию?

Вот так это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поищите папку `.git` (возможно, она скрытая - убедитесь что ваш файловый менеджер показывает скрытые папки). Если вы не собираетесь пользоваться git - просто удалите ее.

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот, я так понимаю, что эта папка может быть в любой папке согласно пути на скриншоте?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Да. Кстати, раз у вас линукс - эта папка будет скрытой гарантировано (точка в начале и делает ее скрытой).

Answer (score 1):

В любом репозитории git есть каталог `.git` туда git помещает все служебные данные. Скорее всего для решения Вашей проблемы достаточно найти и удалить этот каталог

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот, я так понимаю, что эта папка может быть в любой папке согласно пути на скриншоте?

Comment: Скорее всего в последнем каталоге "/home/aleksey/download/TestProjects/BottomBar/.git". И да, она скорее всего скрыта, если пользуетесь наутилусом, Ctrl+H Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

удалить папку .git, которая лежит в корне проекта и скрыта - один вариант. Второй , нажать в вашем редакторе configure, и добавить папку с проектом в исключение. Тогда редактор не будет каждый раз при добавлении спрашивать.